# LESS cpu intensive - alpha video (flv) vs a png sequence

Tags: flash, cpu, flv

Hi
Can anyone tell me which is LESS cpu intensive in flash
1- alpha video rendered as flv
or
2- a png(with alpha) sequence of the same video

Comment: I am not sure, but this would be quite easy for you to test i guess? We use png-sequences because we had some problems with flv dropping frames and seemed more heavy rendering (maybe because of decoding?). The problem with sequences is that the filesize will be much bigger than with flv, so it might not be a good chioce for web apps unless you are using quite short sequences.

Answer (score 0):

Video is less intensive, as the video player in flash is decoupled from the fps of the SWF itself. That is to say that you can run a video player at 30fps, while the SWF runs at 1fps.

You can also take advantage of the gpu through the StageVideo api which means your cpu usage is greatly diminished. Thibault Imbert over at http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/stage_video.html has a good explanation of this.